# Strip out all decimals not next to a number

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to do this and failing miserably.

I want to strip out all decimal points that aren't directly next to a number:

```
Abc 1.2   // Abc 1.2
A.bc 1.2  // Abc 1.2
Abc ..12  // Abc .12
Abc 12    // Abc 12
Abc 1.2.3 // Abc 1.2.3
Abc 1..2  // Abc 1..2
```

Comment: `1..2` , `1.` , `1.2.3` ?

Comment: Is your regex failing or your PHP usage? Can you show what you currently have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookarounds in your regex:

```
(?<!\d)[.](?!\d)
```

- `(?<!\d)` is negative look-behind that asserts if previous position doesn't have digit
- `(?!\d)` is negative look-ahead that asserts if next position doesn't have digit

Replace it by empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fA4mA9/1)

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/iNFD3L)